# Паронимы: великий, величественный, величавый

Tags: егэ, паронимы

Решал задание ЕГЭ, связанное с паронимами. Оказалось, что слова великий и величественный — паронимы, а великий и величавый — нет. Объясните, пожалуйста, почему так.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Интересно, что в *словариках* паронимов, рекомендованных ФИПИ, в [одном](https://ru-paronym.ru/ege.html) есть пара *великий — величественный*, а в [другом](https://rus-ege.sdamgia.ru/rus_sprav?ajax=1&id=251) — тройка: *великий — величавый — величественный*.

Допускаю, что прилагательное "величавый" не было включено составителями в первый, потому что слово довольно редкое и в некоторых словарях имеет пометку *книжн.*
Вот статистика использования в Нацкорпусе:
великий — 30755, величественный — 1108, величавый — 389.

Склоняюсь к тому, что слов в группе должно быть все-таки три (порядок такой: *великий — величественный — величавый*).
[Словарь паронимов русского языка](https://paronymonline.ru/%D0%92)
[Мнение педагога со стажем](https://kak-pravilno-plus.ru/2021/04/30/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB/)

Comment: Получается, что не учитывать слово "величавый" как пароним, — всё же ошибка?

Comment: Про это ничего не могу сказать, *Misha*. Два словаря — два мнения.